Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x00007FFBDC966654 : 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
пишет данную ошибку в данном фрагменте кода
    int MassA(struct EL_SP* p, char* arr[255])
{
    int k = 0;
    printf("\nВведите число К:\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &k);
    printf("\nМассив A:\n");
    struct EL_SP* h;
    for (h = p; h != NULL; h = h->sled)
    {
        if (k < 255) {
            strcpy_s(arr[k++], MAXDL, h->id);
        }
        else {
            printf("Массив A заполнен полностью.\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    return k;
}

Не могу понять в чем ошибка, также ниже указал полный код.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <locale.h>

#define MAXDL 9 
/* макс.длина ид-ра (строки символов с признаком конца '\0' ) */

struct EL_SP /* тип элемента списка */
{
    char id[MAXDL]; /* идентификатор */
    struct EL_SP* sled; /* ссылка на следующий элемент */
};


void Vkl(struct EL_SP** p, char t_id[])
/* Вх. данные: *p - указатель списка идентификаторов в
лексикографическом порядке,
t_id - включаемый в список (текущий) ид-р */
/* Вых. данные: *p */
{
    struct EL_SP* pt, /* указатель включаемого эл-та */
        * k, * j; /* указатели очередного и предыдущего
                  элементов списка */
                  /* выделение памяти для нового эл-та списка */
    pt = (struct EL_SP*)malloc(sizeof(struct EL_SP));
    strcpy_s(pt->id, t_id);
    if (*p == NULL || strcmp(pt->id, (*p)->id) < 0)
    { /* включение ид-ра в начало списка */
        pt->sled = *p;
        *p = pt;
    }
    else
    { /* поиск элемента списка, после которого нужно
      включить идентификатор */
        k = *p; j = *p;
        while (k != NULL && strcmp(pt->id, k->id) >= 0)
        {
            j = k;
            k = k->sled;
        }
        /* включение эл-та *pt после элемента *j */
        j->sled = pt; pt->sled = k;
    }
}

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* функция печати списка */
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------*/
void PechSp(struct EL_SP* p)
/* Вх. данные: p - указатель начала списка */
{
    struct EL_SP* i;/* указатель текущего элемента списка */
    printf("\nРезультат:\n");
    for (i = p; i != NULL; i = i->sled)
    {
        puts(i->id);

    }
}
int MassA(struct EL_SP* p, char* arr[255])
{
    int k = 0;
    printf("\nВведите число К:\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &k);
    printf("\nМассив A:\n");
    struct EL_SP* h;
    for (h = p; h != NULL; h = h->sled)
    {
        if (k < 255) {
            strcpy_s(arr[k++], MAXDL, h->id);
        }
        else {
            printf("Массив A заполнен полностью.\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    return k;
}



/*--------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* О С Н О В Н А Я П Р О Г Р А М М А */
/*-------------------------------------------------------------*/
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    struct EL_SP* p; /* указатель начала списка */
    unsigned n; /* количество идентификаторов */
    unsigned i, size; /* параметр цикла */
    char t_id[MAXDL]; /* текущий идентификатор */
    printf("\nВведите число идентификаторов\n n=");
    scanf_s("%u", &n);
    getchar(); /* пропуск символа "перевод строки" */
    p = NULL; /* список пока пуст */
    printf("Введите идентификаторы ");
    printf("(после каждого нажимайте клавишу <Enter> )\n");
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        gets_s(t_id, MAXDL);
        Vkl(&p, t_id); /* включение ид-ра в список */
    }
    PechSp(p);/* печать списка */
    char* res[255];
    size = MassA(p, res);
    for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
        res[i] = (char*)malloc(MAXDL * sizeof(char));
        printf("%s\0", res[i]);
        free(res[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\nДля завершения нажмите любую клавишу\n");
    _getch();
    return 0;
}


Интересная, однако, логика: сначала попытаться заполнить неинициализированный массив строками, а только потом выделять для них память.

Вы заполняете массив arr в функции MassA до того, как выделили память в main (вызвали malloc). При вызове MassA массив res/arr в общем случае заполнен случайными значениями, поэтому при попытке записи по случайному адресу (strcpy_s(arr[k++], MAXDL, h->id)) возникает исключение. Выделять память необходимо до вызова MassA.

@tiovi Я же правильно изменил
    int MassA(struct EL_SP* p, char* arr[255])
{
    int y = 0;
    printf("\nВведите число К:\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &y);
    printf("\nМассив A:\n");
    struct EL_SP* h;
    for (h = p; h != NULL; h = h->sled)
    {
        if (y < 255) {
            strcpy_s(arr[y++], MAXDL, h->id);
        }
        else {
            printf("Массив A заполнен полностью.\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    return y;
}

Извините если туплю, уже слишком долго с ним сижу)))

имело смысл написать комментарий под ответом пользователя, к которому вы адресуетесь - он получит об этом оповещение. а вот про данный «ответ» оповещения он не получит.
